How to disable new Chrome search engine selection for the EU in Karate
[Developer of Karate making this post to help the community with a new critical change - as we got this report from one of the users].
We were not able to "disable" it in the tests.
Here is the dialog that shows when Chrome is started:

Only workaround is to download Chronium (instead of the full fledged Chrome).
Is there a way to disable this? Since Karate uses a new browser config for each test, we need a solution.

This command line flag should work: --disable-search-engine-choice-screen
So in Karate you can do this:
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', addOptions: [ '--disable-search-engine-choice-screen' ] }

